# nodejs echo to localhost unix socket

Tags: node.js

I would like to have NodeJS API to be able to communicate with program (not wirtten by myself) which listens on localhost Unix socket 5050. I can 'echo' from shell to Unix socket 5050 where this program listens

```
$echo '{"output": "connecting"}' > /dev/tcp/localhost/5050
```

Now, for external programs to write to this localhost socket I need API, don't know how to do it:

```
app.post('/output', function (req, res) {    
    //echo '{"output": "connecting"}' > /dev/tcp/localhost/5050

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the unix socket via the same [`net.connect()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_net_connect_path_connectlistener). From there it's just a matter of writing to the socket (`socket.write()`) once the callback is called.